# /META-INF/resources/.....(No such file or directory) in pom.xml on Eclipse 2020-12 Macbook M1

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven

The error was happened in pom.xml at child project when I updated the parent project. For these project do not appear the error in windows, but happen on my macbook. Please see as below.

[image]

I'm not sure this part in pom.xml of parent make some mistake for this error.

```html
<plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${my.maven.resources}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${basedir}/target/classes
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${basedir}/src/main/webapp
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>WEB-INF/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <targetPath>
                                        /META-INF/resources
                                    </targetPath>
                                </resource>

                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>

                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>
                                            faces-config.xml
                                        </include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Eclipse version 2020-12

JAVA_HOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home

Maven resources plugin version 2.6**

Comment: Remove the complete configuration of maven-resources-plugin except the version you have defined for the plugin. Put your resources into `src/main/resources`. Put the `faces-config.xml` into `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`... do not try to configure things which are done by default...  https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you, I removed others components except version of maven resource plugin. So it can run mvn clean install, but the resouces from directory does not copy to target path. However, thank you very much, at least I know where the problem is.