# Execution tag in maven resources plugin has an error Macbook M1

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I try to update this poject but it has the error in pom.xml at this point.
[image]

The plugin part at the pom.xml

```html
<plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${my.maven.resources}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${basedir}/target/classes
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>WEB-INF/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <targetPath>/META-INF/resources</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                                
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>

                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>faces-config.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Why maven resources plugin does not copy file from directory tag to target tag. It works on windows computer, but does not work in my macbook.

Eclipse version : 2020-12

Maven resouces plugin version : 2.6

Comment: What about the other three questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65855504/6505250), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65847253/6505250) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65821967/6505250)) about Maven and "Macbook M1" in the title that you posted last? Have they been resolved? Has it been confirmed that they are related to "Macbook M1"? There's a comment and an answer you have not yet replied.

Comment: @howlger Sorry for my inappropriate question. I am trying to solve this problem, but it still does not work. and the way that they answered me, I have tried, so It just made me realize that there really is a problem following this post.